# Changing Raspberry Pi board

Tags: openelec

I recently bought new rasp board.  I had about year old board and with sdcard running OpenElec Frodo version.  I plugged that SD card in my new board and tried to boot up.  I believe it should work as whole FS is on SD card.

Am I making some mistake?  In case, if i have to flash new sd card, how do I transfer all of my settings (HDMI etc.) from old to new one, which is really 'PITA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to plug in the card.

If for some reason that doesn't work, according to [this](http://openelec.tv/forum/64-installation/43671-multiple-openelec-installations-with-the-same-configuration) post, you should be able to copy `/storage/.config/` from one OpenELEC SD card to another. It looks like that may be Linux formatted though, so you'd need access to a Linux system to do that. (You could use another SD card to boot the Pi in Rasbpian, and a USB SD card adapter.)

If you've made changes to config.txt, you can simply copy that file across to the new card once OpenELEC is installed as well.